# Расшифровка данных полученных через socket

Tags: python-3.x, сокет

Кратко о ситуации. Дано задание передать данные в стороннее программное обеспечение(далее ПО), написанное на Python 3.8 из ПЛК([ссылка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80)). Предложили делать это через socket. Все данные либо integer либо float.
На данном этапе тестируется конфигурация сервер на Python 3.8 и клиент-ПЛК на CoDeSys 2.3 ([ссылка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoDeSys)).
При построении клиент-серверной структуры чисто на Python есть библиотека pickle и форматирование для сериализации/десериализации данных.
В нашем случае работает обмен согласно теории соединения по протоколу UDP. Открыли сокет, передали запрос, получили ответ и закрыли сокет. Есть свои нюансы, разбираемся. 
Сейчас вопрос в следующем:
1. На стороне клиента-ПЛК формируется массив `sSendToServer:ARRAY [0..5] OF BYTE;` со значениями *[210, 1, 2, 7, 9, count]*. (count - переменная меняется от 0 до 98 чисто ввиде теста)
2. Сервер на python получает данные в таком формате:
recv: b'\xd2\x01\x02\x07\t\x03'
recv: b'\xd2\x01\x02\x07\t\t'
recv: b'\xd2\x01\x02\x07\t\x0f'
recv: b'\xd2\x01\x02\x07\t\x15'
recv: b'\xd2\x01\x02\x07\t\x1b'
recv: b'\xd2\x01\x02\x07\t!'
recv: b"\xd2\x01\x02\x07\t'"
recv: b'\xd2\x01\x02\x07\t-'
recv: b'\xd2\x01\x02\x07\t3'
recv: b'\xd2\x01\x02\x07\t9'
recv: b'\xd2\x01\x02\x07\t?'
recv: b'\xd2\x01\x02\x07\tE' и т.д.
При обратной ситуации, когда сервер-ПЛК (тип данных `sReadFromClient:ARRAY [0..5] OF BYTE;`), а клиент на Python (тип данных `count = bytearray([1, 2, 6, 9, int(b*10), c]`), b и c переменные для эксперимента, считайте их константами) обмен идет и все проходит десериализацию.

Вопрос возникает как расшифровать полученное сообщение от клиента-ПЛК в первоначальный формат.

Comment: Что значит `расшифровать`? Что Вы хотите получить на выходе? `list(b'\xd2\x01\x02\x07\t\x03')` вернёт Вам `[210, 1, 2, 7, 9, 3]`.

Comment: Знания по питону у меня довольно слабые, но Ваш Михаил Муругов ответ решил мою проблему.